# Error: Input string is not in the correct format

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am new to coding so please help me out, the error appears on the commented line below:

```
private void order_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            double[] itemcost = new double[2000];
            itemcost[0] = Convert.ToDouble(pep.Text) * price_pep; // Error here
            itemcost[2] = Convert.ToDouble(all.Text) * price_all;
            itemcost[3] = Convert.ToDouble(haw.Text) * price_haw;
            itemcost[4] = Convert.ToDouble(veg.Text) * price_veg;
            itemcost[5] = Convert.ToDouble(bre.Text) * price_bre;
            itemcost[6] = Convert.ToDouble(chi.Text) * price_chi;
            itemcost[7] = Convert.ToDouble(pot.Text) * price_pot;
            itemcost[8] = Convert.ToDouble(bot.Text) * price_bot;
            itemcost[9] = Convert.ToDouble(cok.Text) * price_cok;
            itemcost[10] = Convert.ToDouble(mou.Text) * price_mou;
        }
```

This is the error that appears:

[image: this is the error that appears]

Comment: Apparently, you're trying to convert to double a value that doesn't represent a correct format of a double number, such as text; Can you trace what value does pep.Text carry??

Comment: May I know whether your issue have been solved or not? if not, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused because the input type cannot be converted to double type, I make a similar code to reproduce the issue, here is my test result：
[image]

We can add try catch to solve this problem, such as:

```
private void order_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            double[] itemcost = new double[2000];
            itemcost[0] = Convert.ToDouble(pep.Text) * price_pep; 
            itemcost[2] = Convert.ToDouble(all.Text) * price_all;
            itemcost[3] = Convert.ToDouble(haw.Text) * price_haw;
            itemcost[4] = Convert.ToDouble(veg.Text) * price_veg;
            itemcost[5] = Convert.ToDouble(bre.Text) * price_bre;
            itemcost[6] = Convert.ToDouble(chi.Text) * price_chi;
            itemcost[7] = Convert.ToDouble(pot.Text) * price_pot;
            itemcost[8] = Convert.ToDouble(bot.Text) * price_bot;
            itemcost[9] = Convert.ToDouble(cok.Text) * price_cok;
            itemcost[10] = Convert.ToDouble(mou.Text) * price_mou;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the correct number");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a conversion error so what this means is your input **string** it failed to convert to a **double**. You should make sure that your variable called **pep** is a number.

Comment: `pep` looks like it should be an input field, not a string. Also, this should probably be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @phuzi yeah you're right, but SO don't let you make comments before the 50 rep mark is reached (don't know why tho), do you know a method to like report (in a neutral way) a question that needs to be transferred as a comment? It would be a useful thing to know, thanks in advance!

Comment: You could have added the code and given a more in depth answer that was worthy of being a proper answer.

Answer (score -2):

Be careful because in coding the decimal separator needs to be a . instead of a , so for example if the user write the number "15,48" the parsing will crash because it expects "15.48", if this is the problem (you can easily check by putting a debug red dot on line 194 and when the button is pressed just hover over pep.Text to see the value stored there, if that's the problem try something like this:
`double.Parse(pep.Text.Replace(",", "."));`
The string.Replace() is a common method that replace a specific char or string value inside a string (in this case ",") with a different value (in this case "." to render the value parsable in double). If you want more info about this [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Don't do replace. Just provide correct format provider that's specific for the culture of the user and just don't care if it's comma, dot or whatever the current culture is using as a decimal separator.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik The replace is useful since you don't need to clarify to the user what to use, and since it doesn't return an error if no correlation is found you can leave it there and it will convert the value only if it's actually needed

Comment: @PawełŁukasik and this is a lot easier instead of having controls to get the culture of the user and then move consequently, and since he is new to coding this can be useful knowledge